# Unknown warning: "Member from unopened namespace"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, intellij-idea, namespaces, compiler-warnings

Within my Pure AS3 app (using IntelliJ) I'm getting the following warning:
"Member from unopened namespace" associated with the instance of the model.

The initial instantiation of the Model is fine (singleton) but each reference to it within the class that it's instantiated after the constructor are throwing the above warning.

The model it's self appear fine as is instantiated without issue from multiple other view classes.

Has anyone come across this before? Interesting that neither SO or Google verbatim throws up any results.

as ever, all suggestions and help appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the full error? As well as an example of code that works and code that doesn't work?

Comment: So if you instantiate from **Class A** and try to access it within **Class A** you get the error, but if you instantiate from **Class B** then **Class A** can now access it without issue? It's strange (or by design). You'll just have to show the model / code or some testable sample like @Aaron suggested.